# Why there are two types of buffer?

Tags: c++, camera, buffer

I have two buffers and I want to calculate the centroid in x and y.

The first one is obtain by an external camera:

```
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
  int index1 = i + j * width;
  centroid[0] += ((double)i) * ((double)buffer1[index1]);
  centroid[1] += ((double)j) * ((double)buffer1[index1]);
}}
```

The second one is obtain by a buffer generated by me:

```
char buffer2[width][height] = {0};
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
  int index2 = j + i * height;
  centroid[0] += ((double)i) * ((double)buffer2[index2]);
  centroid[1] += ((double)j) * ((double)buffer2[index2]);
}}
```

Both buffers have the same width an height. Both algorithm works successfully.
The strange thing is they use a **different index**, so index1 work for buffer1 and index2 work for buffer2. If I swap the indexes, index1 for buffer2 and index2 for buffer1 the centroid is wrong.

The question is: are there two different encoding methods for buffers and in particular for camera buffers? If yes, is there a way to convert one into the other?

Comment: [Row- and column-major ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order)?

Comment: FYI --`char buffer2[width][height] = {0};` -- If `width` and `height` are not constants, this is not valid C++.

Comment: Maybe, you are printing them in wrong manner, and it seems different to you

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I said both code work! I simplify the code for send the message.

Comment: @MiradilZeynalli overlapping the buffer with the centroid I cant fail the print.

Comment: @XaBerr What in the comment I stated was not true?  This is the comment section, so I commented.

Comment: So, if I understood you correctly, just changing variable names from `index1` to `index2` and vice-versa, makes your code to fail, right?

Comment: @MiradilZeynalli exactly

Comment: Can it be that, you are using those index variables, somewhere else, after these loops?

Comment: @MiradilZeynalli no no, I think is a problem with a coding called Format_Grayscale8

Comment: By the way, with `char buffer2[width][height]` then `(double)buffer2[index2]` is highly suspect. With `(double)buffer2[index2]` you essentially let `buffer2[index2]` decay into a pointer, and then cast that pointer into a `double`. Generally speaking, whenever you feel the need to do a C-style casting (like e.g. `(double)buffer2[index2]`) you should take that as a sign that you're doing something wrong which will lead to *undefined behavior*.